# How to make INSERT fail if number of rows exceeds a limit, concurrency-safe?

Tags: mysql, concurrency

Suppose I have a table of Customers and a table of Accounts. Each Customer can have up to 3 Accounts, but not more.

If a Customer wants to `INSERT` the 4th Account, it should fail, and in a safe way when there are multiple concurrent attempts to do it.

If I use an enclosed `SELECT` or `IF` inside the `INSERT` query, there will be a time gap between the different parts of the same query, where concurrent attempts can succeed. This may result in passing the count check successfully but ending up with 4 or more Accounts.

Is there a way to do it, without using locks or transactions? I'd really like it to work like UNIQUE key, when you physically cannot insert a row with the same key.

Comment: If it should work like a unique key, you could *use* a unique key, e.g. `userid, cnt`, where cnt is 1, 2 or 3. You might have to retry if you try to insert 1 and another session did the same.

Comment: Good idea! I could create a special `UNIQUE KEY` for that. Is there a way to make the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work only on some keys and fail on others? Something like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY 'myKey2' UPDATE` ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Any unique key violation will trigger the update. If you have additional requirements like that, you should add them to your question, but at some point, the "i don't want to use transactions"-restriction will become an unreasonable obstacle.